# JavaScript callback functions not executed

Tags: javascript, callback

I just started learning about callback functions. Unfortunately I can't make this altered sample-code work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".closebtn").click(function(){
        function1(someVariable, function() {
          function2(someOtherVariable);
        });
    });


    function function1(param, callback) {
        alert("Erste Funktion");
        callback();
    }

    function function2(param) {
        alert("Zweite Funktion");
    }
})

</script>
```

When I click on the button nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a button with the class `closebtn` and initialising the variable, this code works. What error are you getting?

Comment: You don't show the button so we can only guess that the button does not have the class name closebtn. Maybe you meant the id #closebtn? You should also get some errors since someVariable and someOtherVariable are undefined in the code shown.

Comment: We'd need to see a more complete example. Fundamentally, you're passing the callback into `function1` correctly and calling it correctly. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works for me. Let me know what you think:

```js
// these need to be defined
var someVariable = 'example value';
var someOtherVariable = 'example value';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".closebtn").click(function() {
    function1(someVariable, function() {
      function2(someOtherVariable);
    });
  });


  function function1(param, callback) {
    console.log("Erste Funktion");
    callback();
  }

  function function2(param) {
    console.log("Zweite Funktion");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="closebtn">Close</button>
```

Comment: yes, it works, it was necessary to declare the variables. thank you!